# Where do input files for a VS c++ code need to be if these 2 files are to be checked for syntax errors?

Tags: c++, debugging, syntax, syntax-error, visual-studio-2019

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<stack>
#include<string>


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    stack<char> s;/*created a stack object with char data type*/

    string file_name;
    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    cin >> file_name;

    ifstream testFile;
    testFile.open(file_name, ios::in);
    char ch;
    while (testFile.peek()!=EOF) 
    {
        testFile >> ch;
        if (ch == '[' || ch == '(') 
        {
            s.push(ch);
        }
        if (ch == ']')
        {
            if (s.empty())
            {
                s.push(ch);
            }
            if (s.top() == '[')
            {
                s.pop();
            }
        }
        if (ch == ')')
        {
            if (s.empty())
            {
                s.push(ch);
            }
            if (s.top() == '(')
            {
                s.pop();
            }
        }

    }

    if (s.empty())
    {
        cout << "No Syntax Error Occured.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Syntax Error Occured.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hello eheveryone.  This is my first post on here and I need help with debugging a syntax checker program.  I am sure the stack portion is correct.  I think the error is towards the bottom due to the output not showing the words "Syntax Error Occured"  or "No Syntax Error Occured" I am still learning how to debug and appreciate any advice.  I started IT when covid very first came out and due to remote learning was not able to grasp the fundamentals.  Like debugging.

I expected The output of "Syntax Error Occured" or " No Syntax Error Occured"  but it just exits with code 0.

Comment: I don't understand.  Compilers automatically perform syntax checking, regardless of where the file is located.  Did I miss something?

Comment: I tested the code you uploaded and it outputs "No Syntax Error Occured." Could you please tell me what you typed when you ran this code?